# (Xdebug Profiler) Why are there two cachegrind files generated for one page?

Tags: php, performance, debug, profiling

When I enable **xdebug profiler**, open a page in admin, it generates two cachegrind files with almost identical name

```
cachegrind.out.1498219635_761795.crown__minilio_wp-admin_edit_php
cachegrind.out.1498219639_141988.crown__minilio_wp-admin_edit_php
```

The output name is defined as

```
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%u.%H_%R"
```

I tried another page, got the same result.

Why is that? Which file should I analysis?

Answer (score 0):

@Edward,

You've configured the Xdebug profiler output filename in such a way that it overwrites the output file, each time, you run the process.

`%u, %H, %R` - you mentioned in the output name are called [format specifiers](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#trace_output_name).

There are couple of ways to figure out which file you may want to analyze.

- Use `%t` (timestamp) format specifier in your output filename so you may know which file to analyze based on the timestamp value.
- Instead of enabling the profiler throughout, you could trigger the profiler by passing a query arg as described [here](https://www.wpintense.com/2016/07/26/profiling-wordpress-php-code-using-xprofiler/). This way you will only generate the Xdebug profiler output for the intended page. (**Recommended**)